# R - ggplot geom_histogram drops values

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, polar-coordinates

I'm plotting a polar histogram in ggplot, but I've run into an issue: I can't seem to both plot the bars so that they're center-aligned with their respective tickmarks AND prevent ggplot from dropping any of my values.

This [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSi4L.jpg) illustrates the problem.

Reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(b = c(0:360))
ggplot(data, aes(x = b)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10, fill = 'grey', color = 'black') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 270, by=90), limits = c(0, 360)) +
  coord_polar(start = 0)
```

I get this message, and the bar at 360° is missing:

```
Warning message:
Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

If I add in a boundary input, all the bars appear and no values are dropped. However, the bars are now left-aligned with respect to their tick marks, instead of center aligned.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = b)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10, boundary = 0, fill = 'grey', color = 'black') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 270, by=90), limits = c(0, 360)) +
  coord_polar(start = 0)
```

Ultimately, how can I ensure the bars remain center aligned instead of left-aligned without dropping any values?

Comment: Your data is 361 wide, is that intentional? That won't divide evenly into buckets of 10.

Comment: Yep, that's intentional, the bar at 0/360 will be a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

This took some fiddling. Curious if I'm missing some ggplot options to simplify this.

First, it looks like you want `b == 0:9` and `b == 360` to be in the "0" bin. `geom_histogram` wants to draw those centered at 5, so to make that bin centered at `0`, one option is to manually shift the values over by 5. (See `data$c` below.)

Then, I wanted to make sure that the new -5 to +4 data got binned in the zero group, so I switched `closed = "left"`.

Then, to get the zero bin to show up, we actually need `x` to go back to -5, since ggplot is looking to see if its full width is in the plot area.

At that point, it sees to look right except for the rotation. The first bin's left edge is at 12 o'clock. To get its center aligned there, we need to shift the whole thing by `-pi/36`.

```
data <- data.frame(b = c(0:360))
data$c <- (data$b %% 360) - 5
ggplot(data, aes(x = c)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10, boundary = 5, fill = 'grey', color = 'black', 
                 closed = "left") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 270, by=90), limits = c(-5, 355)) +
  coord_polar(start = -pi/36)
```

[image]

#### Alternate solution

If you're not wedded to `geom_histogram`, I found it simpler to do the summing first and switch to `geom_col`:

```
sum_data <- data %>% dplyr::count(grp = (floor(b/10)*10) %% 360)
ggplot(sum_data, aes(grp, n)) +
  geom_col(fill = 'grey', color = 'black') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 270, by=90), limits = c(-5, 355)) +
  coord_polar(start = -pi/36)
```

[image]